# Tags outside td tags not displayed inside the table

Tags: html

I'm confused as to why `br` tag is not inserted here,
even if i put it inside a `tr` tag.

**HTML:**

```
<table border=1>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <br/>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

An empty space(which is the br) before the table was the **output:**

```
Empty Space
1
2
3
```

I already figured out that it;s possible by putting it inside a `td` tag but I'm still curious on why it can't be  done without the `td` tags.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Because you shouldn't have a `br` there in the first place.

Comment: It is invalid syntax, you should put it inside the `<td>` tag right before there (the `<td>` tag with a "1")

Comment: @asimes The rule's to add every tags inside a td tag?

Comment: Not quite, `<th>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, etc. go outside

Comment: @asimes but it is still possible to add those tags within a td right? adding a table within.

Comment: You could put another `<table>` inside a `<td>` if you wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<br/>` element is invalid in the given position, since HTML syntax does not allow anything between `tr` elements but other `tr` elements (and, in HTML5, `script` elements). When such invalid markup is encountered, the traditional browser behavior is to treat it as if it appeared before the `table` element. This error processing is being standardized in HTML5, in section [Unexpected markup in tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#unexpected-markup-in-tables).

Independently of this, using the `br` element just to create vertical spacing is coarse and unreliable; in HTML5, it is being declared as invalid (somewhat obscurely, see the current description of the [`br` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element)). Using `br` at the end of a `td` element typically creates an empty line there, but this is better achieved by setting `padding-bottom` on the element in CSS.

Comment: It's a great help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid html,if you want an empty space use like this

```
<table border=1>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just that it's not an allowed tag in the way that you use it. Check out the specifications for HTML table tag http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#the-table-element.

Answer (score 0):

it's not in table structure so it doesn't work if you want make space between rows you can large the border size and also use other ways to get your output.